# Fetch attributes values from a json file

Tags: java, json

i am using java language.
i want to print name,MACAddress,active,uniqueDeviceIdentifier values on the same line as per name.
I have tried below code but i am not able to fetch name , i was able to fetch rest of the attributes , i am struggling with name attribute

for below test.json

```json
{
  "names": [
    {
      "name": "ABC",
      "thingTypeName": "SmartPhone",
      "attributes": {
        "MACAddress": "02:00:00:44:11:30",
        "active": "true"
      },
      "version": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "XYZ",
      "thingTypeName": "SmartPhone",
      "attributes": {
        "active": "true",
        "uniqueDeviceIdentifier": "2EAFCEE9-6379-4010-B6B1-8F335D83316F"
      },
      "version": 38
    },
    {
      "name": "YYZ",
      "thingTypeName": "SmartPhone",
      "attributes": {
        "active": "true",
        "uniqueDeviceIdentifier": "2EAFCEE9-6379-4010-B6B1-8F335D833161"
      },
      "version": 39
    },
    {
      "name": "AAA",
      "thingTypeName": "SmartPhone",
      "attributes": {
        "MACAddress": "02:00:00:44:55:32"
      },
      "version": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        Object object;
        try {
            object = jsonParser.parse(new FileReader("src/main/resources/Test.json"));
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) object;
            JSONArray things = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("things");
            Iterator itr = things.iterator();
            System.out.println("thing name"+"^"+"mac Address"+"^"+"activation Code"+"^"+"unique Device Identifier");
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                Object slide = itr.next();
                JSONObject jsonObject2 = (JSONObject) slide;
                JSONObject attributes = (JSONObject) jsonObject2.get("attributes");

                String macAddress = (String) attributes.get("MACAddress");
                String activationCode = (String) attributes.get("activationCode");
                String uniqueDeviceIdentifier = (String) attributes.get("uniqueDeviceIdentifier");       System.out.println(macAddress+"^"+activationCode+"^"+uniqueDeviceIdentifier);
```

**required output**

```
name^MACAddress^active^uniqueDeviceIdentifier

ABC^02:00:00:44:11:30^true^null

XYZ^null^true^2EAFCEE9-6379-4010-B6B1-8F335D83316F

YYZ^null^true^2EAFCEE9-6379-4010-B6B1-8F335D833161

XYZ^02:00:00:44:55:32^null^null
```

Comment: What specific problem are you facing? Just to note: `jsonObject.get("things")` - where is `"things"` in your JSON? Did you mean `jsonObject.get("names")`?

Comment: Yes thats correct it is names

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        Object object;

        try {

            object = jsonParser.parse(new FileReader("src/main/resources/thing.json"));
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) object;


            JSONArray things = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("things");



            Iterator itr = things.iterator();

            System.out.println("Thing_name"+"^"+"Mac_Address"+"^"+"Active"+"^"+"Unique_Device_Identifier");

            JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("things");

            while (itr.hasNext()) {

//                JSONArray attributes1 = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("thingName");

                for (int i = 0; i <jsonArray.size(); i++) {
                Object slide = itr.next();
                JSONObject jsonObject2 = (JSONObject) slide;
                JSONObject attributes = (JSONObject) jsonObject2.get("attributes");

                String macAddress = (String) attributes.get("MACAddress");
                String active = (String) attributes.get("activationCode");
                String uniqueDeviceIdentifier = (String) attributes.get("uniqueDeviceIdentifier");

                System.out.println(((JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i)).get("thingName") + "^" + macAddress + "^" + active + "^" + uniqueDeviceIdentifier);
```